# How to fix 'error: number only refers to a type' for user can include the port in html

Tags: typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, types

I'm beginning for angular user and i try to including Cordova Mqtt Plugin and Paho Libraries into my project.

I tried to change `port: number="";` to `let port: number="";` or `var port: number="";` but didn't work.

My pages.ts :

```
...
export class MainpagePage implements OnInit {

  ...
  port: number = "";
  ...

  ngOnInit() {
    var client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(this.url, number.port, this.clientid);
  }
...
```

the error :

```
    ERROR in src/app/pages/mainpage/mainpage.page.ts:25:46 - error TS2693: 'number' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

    25  var client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(this.url, number.port, this.clientid);
                                                    ~~~~~~

    [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.

    ng run app:ionic-cordova-build --platform=android exited with exit code 1.
```

How i do solve this guys. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You 'cannot' assign a string to a number.

Comment: yap, i did change `port:string="";` to `port:number=""`; but still no lucky

Comment: Please include the relevant part of the code in your question. In your case it looks like `number` might not be a local variable.

Comment: `""` is a `string`. A number is a value that consists of one ore more digits and maybe a decimal separator. (`port: number = 0`) But I suspect you have a field called `number`, which is bad practice, and you should probable change your code to `this.port`.

Comment: `port:number=""` is not valid. Using just double quotes means it is an empty string. But that is not the main issue here. You use  `number.port` as a parameter which it expects `number` to be an object. Instead, you need to use `this.port` as @lukasgeiter answered below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`number.port` should be `this.port` instead:

```js
var client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(this.url, this.port, this.clientid);
//                                          ^^^^
```

Additionally `port: number = ""` is wrong because you're assigning a string value (`""`) to a number member variable. What you likely want is something like this:

```js
port: number = 80; // or some other default value for the port
```

Comment: i tried `this.port` with variable `port:number="";` is same error.

Comment: Are you sure it's the same error? Because the error in your question includes `number.port` which you now have changed to `this.port`.

Comment: yap, that's my first parameter.

Comment: As others in the comments have said (and I've now also added to my answer). You also need to fix the default value of the `port` member.
If you still get an error after that, please update your question with the new error.

Comment: Thanks. @Silvermind is right. a member variable `port:number=0;` to assign `this.port` is works!.